# Django: Improve queryset

Tags: python, django

I currently have the following query set and I wonder if there is a way to bring that part `question.answers.all()` into the `questions=` query set.

```
def get_questions_and_answers(self):
    questions = (
        self.request.event.surveys.get(template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT)
        .questions.exclude(focus=QuestionFocus.EMAIL)
        .all()
    )

    questions_and_answers = {}
    for question in questions:
        questions_and_answers[question] = question.answers.all()

    return questions_and_answers
```

**models.py**

```
class Question(TimeStampedModel[...]):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(related_name='questions')
    type = models.CharField([...])
    focus = models.CharField([...])

class Answer(TimeStampedModel):
    question = models.ForeignKey(related_name='answers')
    response = models.ForeignKey(related_name='answers')
    answer = models.TextField([...])

class Survey(TimeStampedModel):
    event = models.ForeignKey(related_name='surveys')
    template = models.CharField([...])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the related `Answer`s in *bulk*:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_questions_and_answers(self):
    questions = set(self.request.event.surveys.get(
        template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT
    ).questions.exclude(focus=QuestionFocus.EMAIL))

    qids = {q.id for q in questions}
    qst = {q.id: q for q in questions}
    questions_and_answers = defaultdict(list)
    for answer in Answer.objects.filter(question_id__in=qids):
        questions_and_answers[qst[answer.question_id]].append(answer)

    return dict(questions_and_answers)
```

That being  said, you likely do not need to construct all these dictionaries, etc. You likely can just use [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch related answers.

We can `.prefetch_related` here, and then convert it to a dictionary:

```
def get_questions_and_answers(self):
    questions = self.request.event.surveys.get(
        template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT
    ).questions.exclude(focus=QuestionFocus.EMAIL).prefetch_related('answers')

    questions_and_answers = {}
    for qst in questions:
        questions_and_answers[qst] = qst.answers.all()

    return questions_and_answers
```

Comment: Ah so you mean instead of the `qids = [...]` I should just add `.prefetch_related` to the questions query set?

Comment: @JoeyCoder: by using `.prefetch_related('answers')` at the end, it will fetch the answers in bulk as well, and thus if you then access `some_question.answers` these will already be loaded, for *all* questions with one extra query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can like below, small change:

```
questions = (
        self.request.event.surveys.get(template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT)
        .questions.exclude(focus=QuestionFocus.EMAIL)
        .all().prefetch_related('answers')
    )
```

Here on each question, you will get `answers`

for more about that here you go [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)